# Audio analysis in PYTHON

Tags: python-2.7, audio-analysis

I'm working with an external sound card device that have 4 microphone inputs and it's conneceted by usb to my laptop. So I need to take samples of the audio that came from the microphones and do a bar chart or any graphic that shows which mic capture first, second, third and fourth the sound! I had thought to capture that information in a csv file and then do the chart?
Any help please?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You might try the Audio Analysis section of the [Python Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic).  There seem to be some toolkits for audio processing.